# Regular expression preceding comma or ending comma

Tags: javascript, regex

I am not very good with regular expression.

I have a string like:

```
var bigString = 'abc,xyz,def';
```

I want to create a regular expression that it looks for either preceding commas or comma at the end.

e.g:

Valid expressions will be :
abc,
,xyz,
,def

I will appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Are those the only valid values? Is "abc" valid?

Comment: Just alphabetical characters, or alpha-numerics?

Comment: Another question is, WHY? Maybe the problem you're trying to solve doesn't require a regular expression. Can you tell what you're exactly trying to do?

Comment: "Valid expressions will be : abc, ,xyz, ,def" - `/(abc,)|(,xyz,)|(,def)/` QED.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well that regex would be:

```
/(?:,[A-Za-z]+)|(?:[A-Za-z],)/
```

Comment: Shouldn't the last character, the regex delimiter, be `/`?

Comment: This will match items with no commas at all, as they are both followed by ?

Answer (score 1):

```
/(,\w+)|(\w+,)/
```

This one will explicitly match where a comma is either at the beginning or the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

**This should work :** (UPDATED)

```
/(,[\w]+)|([\w]+,)/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are forcing a form, I would use this.
It validates strings 1,2 or 3 as one or more alpha chars with a comma before, after or both.

```
string1 = 'abc,'
string2 = ',xyz,'
string3 = ',def'



/^(?:[a-z]+,|,[a-z]+,?)$/i
```